# JQuery - ScrollTop not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, but I'm at my wit's end and have given up all hope.

Here is my unpacked chrome extension: [nexrem.com/test/extension-test2 - Copy.zip](http://nexrem.com/test/extension-test2%20-%20Copy.zip)

Exhibit A:

- Navigate into the template folder
- run test.html in Chrome
- Click on the "Footer link"
- Observe it scroll correctly to the footer

Exhibit B: Currently, the extension basically replaces the entirety of html on the page.

- Install the unpacked extension
- Go to some website (for the sake of testing, one that isn't filled with all sorts of scripts. or just make a local blank html file)
- Click the extension icon in chrome

You will see the exact same page as when you ran just the test.html ;however, the **jquery scrolling no longer works**. I fail to understand why.

If someone can explain this to me, assist in a solution or at least point in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` **may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser**.

And after digging into your html code after you click the browser action, it seems the body tag is not included.

You can use the following code instead `load`

```
    var template = chrome.extension.getURL('template/test.html');
    console.log(template);

    $.get(template, function(data) {
        document.open();
        document.write(data);
        document.close();
        $.cache = {};
    }, "text");
```